# How to do cross contract e2e tests on ink?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, e2e

I have made a contract in ink! that build fine, and I am trying to make e2e tests. I don't manage to do this even by using the examples in ink! repertory.

My contract is a swap contract: it takes the two contracts address, and allow two users to exchange their tokens.

Below is the beginning of my contract:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_main)]

#[ink::contract]
mod token_swap {
    use ink::storage::Mapping;
    use ink::LangError;
    use ink_env::call::{build_call, ExecutionInput, Selector};
    use ink_env::DefaultEnvironment;

    pub type Swap = (
        AccountId,         // creator
        AccountId,         // token_a
        AccountId,         // token_b
        Balance,           // amount_a
        Balance,           // amount_b
       
    );

    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub enum Error {
        SwapNotFound,
        InsufficientBalance,
        Unauthorized,
        SwapExpired,
        TransferFailed,
        CallFailed,
 
    }

    pub type Result<T> = core::result::Result<T, Error>;

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct TokenSwap {
        pub swaps: Mapping<u64, Swap>,
        pub swap_count: u64,

    }

    #[ink(event)]
    pub struct SwapCreated {
        #[ink(topic)]
        id: u64,
        #[ink(topic)]
        creator: AccountId,
    }

    #[ink(event)]
    pub struct SwapAccepted {
        #[ink(topic)]
        id: u64,
        #[ink(topic)]
        acceptor: AccountId,
    }

    #[ink(event)]
    pub struct SwapDeleted {
        #[ink(topic)]
        id: u64,
    }

    impl TokenSwap {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                swaps: Default::default(),
                swap_count: 0,
  
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]


        fn get_balance(&self, token_contract: AccountId, account: AccountId) -> Result<Balance> {
            let result: core::result::Result<
                core::result::Result<Balance, LangError>,
                ink_env::Error,
            > = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call(token_contract)
                .gas_limit(5000)
                .transferred_value(0)
                .exec_input(
                    ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!("balance_of")))
                        .push_arg(account),
                )
                .returns::<Balance>()
                .try_invoke();

            match result {
                Ok(Ok(balance)) => Ok(balance),
                Ok(Err(_)) => Err(Error::InsufficientBalance),
                Err(_) => Err(Error::CallFailed),
            }
        }

        pub fn create_swap(
            &mut self,
            token_a: AccountId,
            token_b: AccountId,
            amount_a: Balance,
            amount_b: Balance,

        ) -> Result<u64> {

                let caller = self.env().caller();
                let balance_a: Balance = self.get_balance(token_a, caller)?;

                if balance_a < amount_a {
                    return Err(Error::InsufficientBalance);
                }

                let balance_b: Balance = self.get_balance(token_b, caller)?;
                if balance_b < amount_b {
                    return Err(Error::InsufficientBalance);
                }

                self.transfer_token(token_a, caller, self.env().account_id(), amount_a)?;

        

                let new_swap = (
                    caller,
                    token_a,
                    token_b,
                    amount_a,
                    amount_b,
     
                );

                self.swaps.insert(self.swap_count, &new_swap);
                let id = self.swap_count;
                self.swap_count = self.swap_count.checked_add(1).ok_or(Error::CallFailed)?;

                self.env().emit_event(SwapCreated {
                    id,
                    creator: caller,
                });

                Ok(id)
            
        }
```

I want to make e2e tests, so to do that, I wanted to add erc20 contract (from parity) and add it to my cargo toml.
I did that, but it does not work, and I don't understand how to do it ...

Here is the Cargo toml of my contract :

```ini
[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.2.0", default-features = false }
scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.6", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
ink_env = { version = "4.2.1", default-features = false }
ink_lang = { version = "3.4.0", default-features = false }

[dev-dependencies]
ink_e2e = "4.2.1"
erc20 = { path = "../erc20", default-features = false, features = ["ink-as-dependency"] }


[lib]
path = "lib.rs"

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [

    "ink/std",
    "ink_env/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "ink_lang/std",
]
ink-as-dependency = []
e2e-tests = []
```

And here is the test :

```rust
mod e2e_tests {
    use super::*;
    use erc20::erc20::Erc20;
    use ink_e2e::build_message;

    type E2EResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

    #[ink_e2e::test(additional_contracts = "erc20/Cargo.toml ")]
    async fn create_swap_works(mut client: ink_e2e::Client<C, E>) -> E2EResult<()> {
        // Instantiate erc20 contract
        let token_a = Erc20::new(100);
        let token_b = Erc20::new(100);

        let accounts = ink::env::test::default_accounts::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>();


            let amount_a = 100u128;
            let amount_b = 100u32;
  
         let constructor = TokenSwapRef::new_default();
            let contract_acc_id = client
                .instantiate("token_swap", &ink_e2e::bob(), constructor, 0, None)
                .await
                .expect("instantiate failed")
                .account_id;

            let create_swap = build_message::<TokenSwapRef>(contract_acc_id.clone())
                .call(|token_swap| token_swap.create_swap(token_a, token_b, amount_a, amount_b));
            let create_swap_res = client
                .call(&ink_e2e::bob(), create_swap, 0, None)
                await
                .expect("create_swap failed");

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

If someone could explain step by step how to achieve it, I would be so grateful, all I tried did not work ...

Answer (score 0):

If you using `Erc20` contract from the ink! repo, you first need to declare contract module as `pub` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/b4bc91730f5009b19a5b7436c591e3753b4328eb/integration-tests/erc20/lib.rs#L4).

Secondly, you need to use `Erc20Ref` in order to gain an instance of a constructor like so `let mut constructor = Erc20Ref::new(total_supply);`

So you import should be `use erc20::erc20::{Erc20, Erc20Ref};`

Finally, since you message accepts `AccountId` you need to instantiate your two `Erc20` contracts.

```rust
let erc20 = client
    .instantiate("erc20", &ink_e2e::alice(), &mut constructor)
    .submit()
    .await
    .expect("instantiate failed");
```

And you can access the address of the instantiated contract with `erc20.account_id`